# Django form-wizard form save

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I would like to save the form and log in in a session wizard I used to do it using requests how would I use it like so>? Within the done function.

```
class UserWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "registration/signup.html"
    form_list = [SignUpForm]
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        process_data(form_list)
        return redirect('home')

""" def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form}) """
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "registration/signup.html"
    form_list = [SignUpForm]
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        #process_data(form_list)
        form_list[0].save()
        userCreate = form_list[0]
        username = userCreate.cleaned_data.get('username')
        raw_password = userCreate.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        if user:
            auth_login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('home')
```

Just create a user by saving the form and then use auth_login.